# If a raw pointer goes out of scope, does the smart pointer hold the allocated memory?

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers

I can't find a similar example, but is the following valid?

```
std::unique_ptr<int> x;
if (true) {  // assume some condition here which evaluates to true
    int * y = new int(5); // assume a function call here which returns a pointer
    x.reset(y);
}
// is x still holding the memory allocated? 
// Does it matter that y is out of scope here?
cout << *x << endl; // 5
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller The reason I want to do this is because I need to call a function that expects a pointer to pointer, allocates memory and writes some data. So if I want to use smart pointers, I think, I'll have to .reset() after the function call.

Comment: You handed ownership of the memory pointed to by `y` to `x`. `y` is an intermediary, and an unnecessary one at that. A more-proper idiom would have been `x = std::make_unique<int>(5);` and foregoing `y` entirely.

Comment: The code is fine (although maybe not optimal).  The whole idea behind `std::unique_ptr` is that it will release the memory it owns when it goes out of scope (and not before).

Comment: `y` better be out of scope; otherwise you might - mistakenly - probably use it after realsing `x` or `delete` it again; use-after-free and double-delete are the bugs that having `y` in the scope promotes.

Comment: Note that you *can* have a scope without the `if`. https://godbolt.org/z/v76zxhe89

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili That would make the code even more awkward and unrealistic

Comment: @PaulSanders "*The whole idea behind `std::unique_ptr` is that it will release the memory it owns when it goes out of scope (**and not before**)*" - unless you explicitly ask it to release the memory *before* it goes out of scope, via its `operator=`, `release()`, or `reset()` methods

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure.  In the context of the question, I wanted to keep things simple, that's all

Comment: How do you think people used to live with `unique_ptr` before `make_unique` was added to the language?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't see why

Comment: @n.m  In the same way they lived with C++ before `unique_ptr` was added to the standard library.

Comment: @Peter so not using `unique_ptr` at all despite it being a carefully designed part of the language replacing the totally broken `auto_ptr`? Why, that's entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything you allocate with `new` have a life-time until it's passed to `delete`, or the program ends (of course).

The life-time of the variable `y` ends with the block, but not the data it points to.

So yes, that's perfectly valid.

Comment: Otherwise there would be no point in using `std::unique_ptr` ever.